Extending Law of Large Number for Square integrable Martingale
Suppose we have a square integrable martingale $\{M_n\}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}M_t=\langle M\rangle_n=\infty$ a.s. Now, if we have a non-decreasing function $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, and also $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+g(t))^2}dt<\infty$$
Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{M_n}{g(\langle M\rangle_n)}=0$$
I can show in the special case when g(x)=x. However, I don't know how to show for the general case. It would be great if someone can give me some clues on how to do it. Thank you.

Can you recheck your assumptions. For instance, do you mean $\lim_{n\to \infty} \langle M_n\rangle =\infty$ or something like that?

@Raghav thanks for pointing out, I fixed that

I would use the methods in Liptser's book(Liptser, R. Sh. and A. N. Shiryayev,  Theory of Martingales, Kluwer Academic Publishers,(1989).  $\S$2.6, pp.130--- and Th.2.6.10, pp.144) to prove the following strong LLN for a square integrable martingale $M=\{M_t, t\ge 0\}$,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{M_t}{g(\langle M\rangle_t)}=0,\quad \text{a.s..} \tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{align*}
 h(t) &= 1+g(\langle M\rangle_t), \qquad t\ge 0, \\
 N(t) &= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{h(s)}\,\mathrm{d}M_s = \Big(\frac{1}{h}\cdot M\Big)_t, \qquad t\ge 0   \tag{2}
\end{align*}
then $h$ is a  positive right-continuous increasing  process on $\mathbb{R}_+$, $N\in\mathfrak{M}^2_{\text{loc}}$(locally square integrable martingale) and
\begin{align*}
 M &= h\cdot N  \\
  &= hN- N_- \cdot h. \qquad (\text{integrate by parts} )
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{M}{h}=N- \frac{1}{h}\big(N_- \cdot h\big).               \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Under the following assumption,
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{[1+g(t)]^2}\,\mathrm{d}t<\infty,   \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
we would prove
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}\big(\lim_{t\to\infty} \langle N \rangle_t < \infty \big)= 1. \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
From (2),
\begin{align*}
 \langle N \rangle_t
 &= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle M \rangle_s }{[h(s)]^2} \\
 & =\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle M \rangle_s }{
  [1+g(\langle M\rangle_s)]^2 }.
\end{align*}
We need transform above Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral to ordinary Lebesgue integral.
Let
\begin{equation*}
 c(u)= \inf\{s:\langle M\rangle_s>u\}, \quad u\in\mathbb{R}_+,
\end{equation*}
then $c(u)$  is a non-negative right-continuous increasing function on $\mathbb{R}_+$(called the right inverse function of $\langle M\rangle $).
Meanwhile,
\begin{gather*}
 c_-(u)=c(u-)=\lim_{u\upuparrows t }c(u) = \inf\{s:\langle M\rangle_s\ge u\}, \quad t >0,\\
 \langle M\rangle_{c(u)}\ge \langle M\rangle_{c_-(u)}\ge u,\quad u\in \mathbb{R}_+. \tag{6}
\end{gather*}
Then using the Lebesgue's Lemma(Please refer to  C. Dellacherie $\&$ P. Meyer, Probabilities and Potential B, volume 72 of North-Holland Mathematics Studies.
North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1982. pp.119-121,  Th IV.55.) get
\begin{align*}
  \langle N \rangle_t
   & =\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle M \rangle_s }{
  [1+g(\langle M\rangle_s)]^2 }\\
   & = \int_{0}^{+\infty}I(c(u)\le t)\frac{\mathrm{d}u }{
    [1+g(\langle M\rangle_{c(u)})]^2 }  \quad (\text{by Lebesgue's Lemma})\\
   &\le \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{[1+g(u)]^2 }\,\mathrm{d}u . \qquad (\text{by }(6))  
\end{align*}
Hence $\mathsf{P}\big(\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \langle N \rangle_t < \infty \big)= 1$ and
\begin{equation*}
 N_{\infty}=\lim_{t\to\infty}  N_t\quad \text{exist and finite a.s..}\tag{7}
\end{equation*}
From (7),
\begin{equation*}
   \lim_{t\to\infty}\Big[\frac{1}{h}(N_- \cdot h)\Big]_t  =\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{h(t)}\int_{0}^{t}N(s-)\,\mathrm{d}h(s)
 =N_{\infty}, \qquad  \text{ a.s..} \tag{8}
\end{equation*}
Now substituting (7),(8) in (3), get
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{M_t}{1+g(\langle M\rangle_t)}
 =\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{M_t}{h(t)}=0, \qquad  \text{ a.s..} \tag{9} 
\end{equation*}
At last, from $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\langle M\rangle_t=\infty $ and
$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}g(\langle M\rangle_t)=\infty $ a.s.,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{g(\langle M\rangle_t)}{1+g(\langle M\rangle_t)}=1,  \qquad  \text{ a.s..}
 \tag{10}
\end{equation*}
Due to  (9)(10), (1) is true,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{M_t}{g(\langle M\rangle_t)}=0,\quad \text{a.s.}.
\end{equation*}
